# Input mode instead of input box in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I am creating a web-based self-service for a store.
Right now everything works fine in the sense that the customer can scan a loyalty card into an html input box, and then their name will show in a box on the screen (using javascript, php and a mysql database) and they can scan products, which then shows the price and other product information.

I am just starting to design the user interface and that's where I've got problems. I don't want people to have to select the loyalty card input box to scan their card and then select the product input box to scan their products. I've experimented with moving the actual input boxes out of the website

```
position:absolute; left:-9999px
```

and then use javascript to autoselect the right input box.

```
window.onload = function () {
    input = document.getElementById('input');
    input.focus();
    input.select();
}
```

That works fine when people do what they are expected to do. But that won't work for real-life situations.

I suppose I could do something like this (found this on stackoverflow):

```
<input onblur="this.focus()" autofocus />
```

to keep the input box selected, but when I am using multiple input boxes that feels like a bad solution (would need to use javascript to change which input box this applies to in every situation).

That's why I'm wondering if there is a way to not have to have a specific input box, but rather have the website be in input mode, so that whatever else is happening on the website, and whether the user accidentally taps outside the input "box", the website is in input mode (for a specific "variable", e.g. loyalty card or product) and any scan would be captured by the website. 
There would need to be a way to move out of the input mode by tapping "Pay now", "Remove product" or something like that, but other than that, there would be no way to get out of the input mode.

Is there a way to make that happen?